# application:openURL:options: not called after opening universal link

Tags: ios, swift, ios-universal-links

I've set up universal links with the Branch SDK. The links are opening the app correctly, and `application:continueUserActivity:restorationHandler:` is called, but not `application:openURL:options:'

```
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    Branch.getInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)
    return true
}
```

The deprecated `application:openURL:sourceApplications:annotation` is also not called.  `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` and `willFinishLaunchingWithOptions` both return true.

What could possibly causing openURL to not be called when the app opens from tapping a universal link?

Comment: try this. delete the app and install again.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq Deleted app, deleted derived data, performed a clean, rebuilt... still not calling that method when the app opens.

Comment: Its clearly stated in [the documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Conceptual/AppSearch/UniversalLinks.html), that for Universal Links, the `continueUserActivity` method is called. As simple as that.

Comment: @MohammadSadiq you save my life, 老铁666

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Clay from [Branch](http://branch.io) here.

The `application:openURL:sourceApplications:annotation` function (now deprecate to `application(_:open:options:)`) is actually only called in response to the old Apple Linking system of standard URI schemes.

Universal links are actually handled within the `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)` function.

```
// Respond to URI scheme links
func application(_ app: UIApplication, open url: URL, options: [UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsKey : Any] = [:]) -> Bool {
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    Branch.getInstance().application(app, open: url, options: options)

    // do other deep link routing for the Facebook SDK, Pinterest SDK, etc
    return true
}

// Respond to Universal Links
func application(_ application: UIApplication, continue userActivity: NSUserActivity, restorationHandler: @escaping ([Any]?) -> Void) -> Bool {
    // pass the url to the handle deep link call
    Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)

    return true
}
```

Your deep link handling should mostly be dealt with in your handler callback:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplicationLaunchOptionsKey: Any]?) -> Bool {
  let branch: Branch = Branch.getInstance()
  branch?.initSession(launchOptions: launchOptions, deepLinkHandler: { params, error in
    if error == nil {
        // params are the deep linked params associated with the link that the user clicked -> was re-directed to this app
        print("params: %@", params.description)
    }
   })
   return true
}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response Clay. So as long as I'm targeting iOS 10+, I don't actually need the `application(_:open:options:)` function, correct? In `application(_:continue:restorationHandler:)`, can you explain the purpose of `Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)`? I'm not quite sure what the point of it is if I'm just going to handle the link in Branch handler callback.

Comment: Correct, you do not need `application(_:open:options:)` if you are targeting iOS 10+. The `Branch.getInstance().continue(userActivity)` allows Branch to handle restoration from an `NSUserActivity`. The userActivity is the `NSUserActivity` that caused the app to be opened. This method is how Branch processes the Universal Link. You only need to worry about the call back in the  `branch?. initSession` function. That is where all of the link processing is handled